# Как сравнить значения в группе с соответствующим (сгруппированному) значению из другого DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Есть два DataFrame со следующими данными:

Первый DataFrame сгруппирован по 30 минут (пример входных данных, первые 3 группы):

```
                      high     low
datetime                           
2018-09-17 10:00:00  108380  108000
2018-09-17 10:01:00  108110  107960
2018-09-17 10:02:00  108070  107960
2018-09-17 10:03:00  108080  107950
2018-09-17 10:04:00  108150  108040
2018-09-17 10:05:00  108070  107930
2018-09-17 10:06:00  107960  107650
2018-09-17 10:07:00  107880  107760
2018-09-17 10:08:00  107920  107830
2018-09-17 10:09:00  107920  107810
2018-09-17 10:10:00  107940  107790
2018-09-17 10:11:00  107820  107770
2018-09-17 10:12:00  107890  107800
2018-09-17 10:13:00  107960  107860
2018-09-17 10:14:00  107930  107800
2018-09-17 10:15:00  107850  107780
2018-09-17 10:16:00  107830  107750
2018-09-17 10:17:00  107860  107720
2018-09-17 10:18:00  107930  107890
2018-09-17 10:19:00  107900  107820
2018-09-17 10:20:00  107890  107810
2018-09-17 10:21:00  107810  107750
2018-09-17 10:22:00  107800  107750
2018-09-17 10:23:00  107850  107780
2018-09-17 10:24:00  107830  107760
2018-09-17 10:25:00  107750  107680
2018-09-17 10:26:00  107790  107700
2018-09-17 10:27:00  107860  107730
2018-09-17 10:28:00  107800  107750
2018-09-17 10:29:00  107860  107810
                       high     low
datetime                           
2018-09-17 10:30:00  107900  107810
2018-09-17 10:31:00  107970  107890
2018-09-17 10:32:00  108010  107940
2018-09-17 10:33:00  108020  107960
2018-09-17 10:34:00  108080  107980
2018-09-17 10:35:00  108060  108010
2018-09-17 10:36:00  108060  108010
2018-09-17 10:37:00  108110  108020
2018-09-17 10:38:00  108090  108020
2018-09-17 10:39:00  108070  107990
2018-09-17 10:40:00  108040  107900
2018-09-17 10:41:00  107920  107880
2018-09-17 10:42:00  107920  107850
2018-09-17 10:43:00  107970  107910
2018-09-17 10:44:00  107960  107910
2018-09-17 10:45:00  107940  107910
2018-09-17 10:46:00  107940  107930
2018-09-17 10:47:00  107910  107880
2018-09-17 10:48:00  107930  107890
2018-09-17 10:49:00  107870  107850
2018-09-17 10:50:00  107880  107750
2018-09-17 10:51:00  107800  107710
2018-09-17 10:52:00  107790  107680
2018-09-17 10:53:00  107780  107540
2018-09-17 10:54:00  107560  107520
2018-09-17 10:55:00  107620  107540
2018-09-17 10:56:00  107630  107560
2018-09-17 10:57:00  107680  107640
2018-09-17 10:58:00  107640  107610
2018-09-17 10:59:00  107650  107560
                       high     low
datetime                           
2018-09-17 11:00:00  107590  107350
2018-09-17 11:01:00  107430  107350
2018-09-17 11:02:00  107480  107460
2018-09-17 11:03:00  107400  107400
2018-09-17 11:04:00  107420  107380
2018-09-17 11:05:00  107450  107430
2018-09-17 11:06:00  107450  107430
2018-09-17 11:07:00  107420  107370
2018-09-17 11:08:00  107430  107390
2018-09-17 11:09:00  107460  107400
2018-09-17 11:10:00  107440  107350
2018-09-17 11:11:00  107500  107460
2018-09-17 11:12:00  107590  107510
2018-09-17 11:13:00  107580  107530
2018-09-17 11:14:00  107570  107530
2018-09-17 11:15:00  107640  107570
2018-09-17 11:16:00  107670  107650
2018-09-17 11:17:00  107670  107620
2018-09-17 11:18:00  107680  107650
2018-09-17 11:19:00  107660  107660
2018-09-17 11:20:00  107660  107640
2018-09-17 11:21:00  107650  107580
2018-09-17 11:22:00  107570  107530
2018-09-17 11:23:00  107550  107480
2018-09-17 11:24:00  107630  107560
2018-09-17 11:25:00  107690  107620
2018-09-17 11:26:00  107680  107600
2018-09-17 11:27:00  107600  107570
2018-09-17 11:28:00  107590  107530
2018-09-17 11:29:00  107640  107550
```

Второй DataFrame интересуют данные столбца ['last'] (пример входных данных первые 3 строки):

```
                     last   vol
datetime        
2018-09-17 10:00:00 107800  104
2018-09-17 10:30:00 108030  133
2018-09-17 11:00:00 107550  190
```

Каждое значение столбца ['last'] для каждой группы:
значение 107800 для первой группы, значение 108030 для второй группы, значение 107550 для третьей группы и т.д.

Как сравнить значение ['last'] с соответствующей группой?
И получить список вида (пример):

```
['more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'more',
 'equally',
 'less',
 'less',
 'less',
 'less',
 'less',
 'less',
 'less',
 'less',
 'less']
```

Comment: непонятно как вы получили данный выходной дата сет из входного...

Comment: Извиняю что ввожу в заблуждение. Входные данные не точные, только для примера, я их по времени обрезал. А выходные такого вида получаю с помощью срезов, приводил в примере. Только не пойму как срезы объединить для дальнейшей работы? Пробовал в список добавить, но через цикл не получается работать со столбцами 'high' и 'low' в каждой группе, а отдельно по каждому срезу могу.

Comment: Я не смогу ответить на вопрос не поняв что вы хотите получить на выходе из входных данных. Лучше приведите __небольшой__ пример входных данных (по 2-3 строки на группу) и то что должно получиться из этого дата сета

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def cmp(a, b):
    return np.where(a>b, 'more', np.where(a<b, 'less', 'equally'))

df1['new'] = (df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(level='datetime', freq='30min'))
                 ['high']
                 .transform(lambda x: cmp(x, df2.loc[x.name, 'last'])))
```

результат:

```
In [474]: df1
Out[474]:
                       high     low      new
datetime
2018-09-17 10:00:00  108380  108000     more
2018-09-17 10:01:00  108110  107960     more
2018-09-17 10:02:00  108070  107960     more
2018-09-17 10:03:00  108080  107950     more
2018-09-17 10:04:00  108150  108040     more
2018-09-17 10:05:00  108070  107930     more
2018-09-17 10:06:00  107960  107650     more
2018-09-17 10:07:00  107880  107760     more
2018-09-17 10:08:00  107920  107830     more
2018-09-17 10:09:00  107920  107810     more
2018-09-17 10:10:00  107940  107790     more
2018-09-17 10:11:00  107820  107770     more
2018-09-17 10:12:00  107890  107800     more
2018-09-17 10:13:00  107960  107860     more
2018-09-17 10:14:00  107930  107800     more
2018-09-17 10:15:00  107850  107780     more
2018-09-17 10:16:00  107830  107750     more
2018-09-17 10:17:00  107860  107720     more
2018-09-17 10:18:00  107930  107890     more
2018-09-17 10:19:00  107900  107820     more
2018-09-17 10:20:00  107890  107810     more
2018-09-17 10:21:00  107810  107750     more
2018-09-17 10:22:00  107800  107750  equally
2018-09-17 10:23:00  107850  107780     more
2018-09-17 10:24:00  107830  107760     more
2018-09-17 10:25:00  107750  107680     less
2018-09-17 10:26:00  107790  107700     less
2018-09-17 10:27:00  107860  107730     more
2018-09-17 10:28:00  107800  107750  equally
2018-09-17 10:29:00  107860  107810     more
2018-09-17 10:30:00  107900  107810     less
2018-09-17 10:31:00  107970  107890     less
2018-09-17 10:32:00  108010  107940     less
2018-09-17 10:33:00  108020  107960     less
2018-09-17 10:34:00  108080  107980     more
2018-09-17 10:35:00  108060  108010     more
2018-09-17 10:36:00  108060  108010     more
2018-09-17 10:37:00  108110  108020     more
2018-09-17 10:38:00  108090  108020     more
2018-09-17 10:39:00  108070  107990     more
2018-09-17 10:40:00  108040  107900     more
2018-09-17 10:41:00  107920  107880     less
2018-09-17 10:42:00  107920  107850     less
2018-09-17 10:43:00  107970  107910     less
2018-09-17 10:44:00  107960  107910     less
2018-09-17 10:45:00  107940  107910     less
2018-09-17 10:46:00  107940  107930     less
2018-09-17 10:47:00  107910  107880     less
2018-09-17 10:48:00  107930  107890     less
2018-09-17 10:49:00  107870  107850     less
2018-09-17 10:50:00  107880  107750     less
2018-09-17 10:51:00  107800  107710     less
2018-09-17 10:52:00  107790  107680     less
2018-09-17 10:53:00  107780  107540     less
2018-09-17 10:54:00  107560  107520     less
2018-09-17 10:55:00  107620  107540     less
2018-09-17 10:56:00  107630  107560     less
2018-09-17 10:57:00  107680  107640     less
2018-09-17 10:58:00  107640  107610     less
2018-09-17 10:59:00  107650  107560     less
2018-09-17 11:00:00  107590  107350     more
2018-09-17 11:01:00  107430  107350     less
2018-09-17 11:02:00  107480  107460     less
2018-09-17 11:03:00  107400  107400     less
2018-09-17 11:04:00  107420  107380     less
2018-09-17 11:05:00  107450  107430     less
2018-09-17 11:06:00  107450  107430     less
2018-09-17 11:07:00  107420  107370     less
2018-09-17 11:08:00  107430  107390     less
2018-09-17 11:09:00  107460  107400     less
2018-09-17 11:10:00  107440  107350     less
2018-09-17 11:11:00  107500  107460     less
2018-09-17 11:12:00  107590  107510     more
2018-09-17 11:13:00  107580  107530     more
2018-09-17 11:14:00  107570  107530     more
2018-09-17 11:15:00  107640  107570     more
2018-09-17 11:16:00  107670  107650     more
2018-09-17 11:17:00  107670  107620     more
2018-09-17 11:18:00  107680  107650     more
2018-09-17 11:19:00  107660  107660     more
2018-09-17 11:20:00  107660  107640     more
2018-09-17 11:21:00  107650  107580     more
2018-09-17 11:22:00  107570  107530     more
2018-09-17 11:23:00  107550  107480  equally
2018-09-17 11:24:00  107630  107560     more
2018-09-17 11:25:00  107690  107620     more
2018-09-17 11:26:00  107680  107600     more
2018-09-17 11:27:00  107600  107570     more
2018-09-17 11:28:00  107590  107530     more
2018-09-17 11:29:00  107640  107550     more
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос.

```
In [79]: (df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(level='datetime', freq='30min'))
             .apply(lambda x: x > df2.loc[x.name, 'last']))
Out[79]:
                      high    low
datetime
2018-09-17 10:00:00   True   True
2018-09-17 10:01:00   True   True
2018-09-17 10:03:00   True   True
2018-09-17 10:10:00   True  False
2018-09-17 10:11:00   True  False
2018-09-17 10:21:00   True  False
2018-09-17 10:29:00   True   True
2018-09-17 10:30:00  False  False
2018-09-17 10:31:00  False  False
2018-09-17 10:50:00  False  False
2018-09-17 10:57:00  False  False
2018-09-17 10:59:00  False  False
```

Пояснение: при группировке создаётся дополнительный атрибут `name`, который равен сгруппированному значению. В вашем случае его можно использовать для поиска соответствующей строки из `df2`.

Пример - распечатаем значения атрибута `name`:

```
In [80]: df1.groupby(pd.Grouper(level='datetime', freq='30min')).apply(lambda x: print(x.name))
2018-09-17 10:00:00
2018-09-17 10:00:00
2018-09-17 10:30:00
Out[80]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

---

Исходные DataFrame's:

```
In [77]: df1
Out[77]:
                       high     low
datetime
2018-09-17 10:00:00  108380  108000
2018-09-17 10:01:00  108110  107960
2018-09-17 10:03:00  108080  107950
2018-09-17 10:10:00  107940  107790
2018-09-17 10:11:00  107820  107770
2018-09-17 10:21:00  107810  107750
2018-09-17 10:29:00  107860  107810
2018-09-17 10:30:00  107900  107810
2018-09-17 10:31:00  107970  107890
2018-09-17 10:50:00  107880  107750
2018-09-17 10:57:00  107680  107640
2018-09-17 10:59:00  107650  107560

In [78]: df2
Out[78]:
                       last  vol
datetime
2018-09-17 10:00:00  107800  104
2018-09-17 10:30:00  108030  133
```

Comment: Все верно, только возможно что бы сохранялась группировка по 30 минут?

Comment: @tortuga, поэтому я и попросил привести в вопросе пример того что вы хотите получить на выходе ;-)

Comment: @tortuga, а зачем приводить данные в моем ответе?? Вы же можете [отредактировать ваш вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/887392/edit). Я так и не понял откуда берутся эти данные и как они коррелируют с входными данными из вопроса. Советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/) и отредактировать ваш вопрос соответственно